# When using window.open(), if the new window freeze so too does the parent

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables, window.open

Pretty simple question, really. I've looked everywhere for someone with the exact issue I'm having with no luck...

In tab "A" I call `window.open()`. The new tab (tab "B") begins to load and its script contains some ajax. The ajax call it makes takes a very long time (this is intentional for now as I am attempting to handle a lengthy ajax call). When tab "B" freezes after a little more than 10 seconds so too does tab "A".

I've tried calling `window.open("url", "_blank");` as well as `window.open("url");` and neither seems to solve the problem.

To make things more confusing I tried the experiment such that tab "B" opens, ajax **doesn't** timeout and everything works fine. **Then** I change the URL parameters in tab "B" (this is what sends database parameters through ajax and is the cause of the lengthy request) and when it times out as expected it **still** freezes window "A".

I'm sure I'm missing something. What does tab "B" have to do with tab "A" after the window.open() call has completed. I don't understand how they are still tied to each other. While all of this is going on other tabs work just fine.

For the record I'm using Chrome on a Mac but saw a similar "quantum entanglement," let's call it, in Safari as well.

Also, both pages use the DataTables jQuery plugin. It's in the API that the ajax calls are being made. I can't imagine how DataTables could be the culprit here, though...

Any ideas, SO community???

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: Seems, like you send synchrone ajax call. Can you provide some code?

Comment: Can we assume here you have no code in the child or parent windows that access the other window?  Show code Show code (from both perhaps)

Comment: It's going to be rather difficult to provide much code as there is a lot going on on each page. It is true that **something** happening on either page could be causing the relationship. I can confidently say that no, there is no intentional referencing of either page from the other one. My basic question is essentially: After a call to window.open() is there something going on to connect the two "pages/tabs/windows?" Is this behavior as designed? If not, then there may be something in my code in which case, that's on me to root it out. Thanks, so far.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this ?

Answer (score 30):

According to the documentation:  (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Window_features) window.open() currently supports features. Hence we can pass noreferrer or noopener as shown below, which does not freeze or block the parent window.

```
  window.open(hostUrl, '_blank', 'noreferrer')
```

Comment: wow life saver, thanks!

Comment: Pretty much saved my life, thanks! lol

Answer (score 17):

That's because the new window is opened in the same process with the opener window.

*To cause a link to open in a separate process from your web page, just add rel="noreferrer" and target="_blank" as attributes to the  tag, and then point it at a URL on a different domain name. For example:
`<a href="http://www.google.com" rel="noreferrer" target="_blank">Google</a>`*

source: https://blog.chromium.org/2009/12/links-that-open-in-new-processes.html

Answer (score -1):

I guess you need to remove a parent reference from your window object like this:

```
openedWindow.opener = null;
```

Answer (score -1):

use `window.focus()` after you open the window.