# Issue with Opening and Printing in New Tab in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, google-chrome, printing

Hi and thank you for your response.

I'm facing a problem when attempting to open a new tab in Chrome and Edge and then print the content of that tab. My project is built using Angular.

Steps to Reproduce:

Step 1: From Tab 1, click a button to open a new tab. After the new tab is loaded, it automatically calls `window.print();`.

```
print() {
    // Your content
    let content = `
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Print Page</title>
      </head>
      <body onload="window.print()">
        Content
      </body>
    </html>
    `;

    // Create a Blob from the HTML content
    let blob = new Blob([content], { type: 'text/html' });

    // Create a URL for the Blob
    let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    // Open a new tab with the created URL
    window.open(url, '_blank');

    // Release the URL object after the new tab is opened
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }
```

Step 2: Close the newly opened tab (click 'x' icon).

After following the outlined steps, the new tab opens successfully, but upon closing the tab using the 'x' icon, Tab 1 (the original tab) becomes partially or fully disabled. This results in a loss of interactivity, and the issue persists until a manual refresh of Tab 1.
Expected Behavior:
Closing the newly opened tab should not affect the functionality or disable any elements in Tab 1.

Code Sample:

[Link to StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-14-demo-hjo4jz)

Demo Link:

[Live Demo](https://angular-14-demo-hjo4jz.stackblitz.io)

Thanks again for your valuable help!

Answer (score 0):

One way to address this issue is to separate the printing functionality from the tab opening process. Instead of automatically invoking `window.print()` upon opening the new tab, you can let the user trigger the printing action manually. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
print() {
    // Your content
    let content = `
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Print Page</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        Content
        <script>
          // Function to trigger printing when the page is loaded
          function printPage() {
            window.print();
          }
          // Call the printPage function after a delay to ensure proper rendering
          setTimeout(printPage, 1000); // Adjust the delay as needed
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
    `;

    // Create a Blob from the HTML content
    let blob = new Blob([content], { type: 'text/html' });

    // Create a URL for the Blob
    let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    // Open a new tab with the created URL
    let newTab = window.open(url, '_blank');

    // Release the URL object after the new tab is opened
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

    // Listen for the close event on the new tab
    newTab.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
      // Perform any cleanup or necessary actions here
      // For example, re-enable elements in Tab 1 if needed
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer from [Sasi Kumar M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957480/when-using-window-open-if-the-new-window-freeze-so-too-does-the-parent) finally helped me solve your issue. Please call the `window.open` with the third parameter `noreferrer` which does not pass a reference to the opening tab and this seems to fix the issue:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

/**
 * https://javascript.plainenglish.io/the-new-features-of-angular-v14-851995870f59
 *
 * Planning on joining Medium? Membership is $5/month and gives unlimited access
 * to all stories on Medium. Use my referral link:
 * https://vkagklis.medium.com/membership
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule],
  template: `
    <input >
    <br />
    <button (click)="print()">Print</button>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  print() {
    let content = `
          <html>
            <head>
              <title>New Tab</title>
            </head>
            <body onload="window.print()">
              Content
            </body>
          </html>
        `;

    // Create a Blob from the HTML content
    let blob = new Blob([content], { type: 'text/html' });

    // Create a URL for the Blob
    let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    // Open a new tab with the created URL
    window.open(url, '_blank', 'noreferrer'); // <- changed here!

    // Release the URL object after the new tab is opened
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }
}
```

Please note stackblitz may not work, I found the solution in my local system, would suggest you to do the same!

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-14-demo-dkufho?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)